# Trimming exterior empty space with ImageMagick does not work on scanned documents

Tags: imagemagick, scanner, documents, scanning, image-manipulation

Given an image that has some actual content inside and usually some unwanted white or black or transparency around that, I would like to trim or crop the exterior parts using ImageMagick.

The following image has been drawn digitally on a computer (on the HTML `<canvas>`):

[image: canvas.png]

The following ImageMagick command is what I tried:

```
$ convert canvas.png -trim +repage canvas_trimmed.png
```

And it worked perfectly:

[image: canvas_trimmed.png]

So this is exactly what I want. But now I want this to work with scanned documents as well, which are not as "perfect" as computer-generated images, i.e. they have more shades of "white" and "black" and no transparency which would be easier to detect. Sometimes, they even have some black bars around the white background of the paper because the area of the scanner is larger than the paper:

[image: scan.jpg]

With this image, I tried the following commands in the given order, each trying to be more aggressive, but none yielding any results – you can't see any difference between the original image and the "trimmed" images, i.e. the trimming or cropping does not work at all:

```
$ convert scan.jpg -trim +repage scan_trimmed.jpg
$ convert scan.jpg -fuzz 10% -trim +repage scan_trimmed.jpg
$ convert scan.jpg -fuzz 60% -trim +repage scan_trimmed.jpg
$ convert scan.jpg -fuzz 60% -bordercolor white -border 1x1 -trim +repage scan_trimmed.jpg
$ convert scan.jpg -fuzz 60% -bordercolor black -border 1x1 -trim +repage scan_trimmed.jpg
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can the ImageMagick command that reliably trims computer-generated images be modified so that it trims scanned documents of the style above just as reliably?

Comment: Why complicate things? Use the auto-crop function in your scanner driver and you are done. Some scanner drivers also offer removal of dark edges as shown on your scanned example. Perhaps ImageMagick offers such a dark edges removal as well.

Comment: @user291737 Thanks! I wish that was possible, but it's not. It's easy to imagine some of the use cases where it's not possible: Your scanner may not support that feature, you may be doing the processing for somebody else (who used their scanner which you don't have access to), etc.

Comment: How about potentially testing with [-shave](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#shave) and see if you can simple [shave](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#shave) off the edges and then use the logic you use? Let me know if this helps but look over ***both*** these links when you get a chance

Comment: Have a look at Fred's ImageMagick Scripts [autotrim](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/autotrim/) and [multicrop](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop/). See this [related article](http://start.sethanil.com/exploring-software/49-image_cropping).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [-shave](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#shave) and simply [shave](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#shave) off the edges and then use the logic you use afterwards to process accordingly.

> **Note:** *The amount you [shave](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#shave) off (e.g. the
>   argument after "-shave" `40x40` or `10x10`, etc. ) is important so be
>   sure to test thoroughly to ensure this setting works universally in
>   your environment for your images.*

**Example Logic**

```
@ECHO ON

SET Convert="C:\Program Files\ImageMagick\Convert.exe"
%convert% C:\Folder\Circle.jpg -shave 40x40 C:\Folder\ShavedCircle.jpg
<The rest of your logic against C:\Folder\ShavedCircle.jpg now>
```

### Before

[image]

### After

[image]

---

### Further Resources

- > **Shave, removing edges from a image**
  >
  > The reverse of the "-border" or "-frame" operators, is
  >   "[-shave](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/option_link.cgi?shave)",
  >   which if given the same arguments, will remove the space added by
  >   these commands.
  >
  > The main thing to keep in mind about these three operators is that
  >   they add and remove space on opposite sides of the images, not just
  >   one side, or adjacent sides.
  >
  > If you want to only remove one edge of an image, then you will need to
  >   use the "-chop" operator instead. (See the Chop Examples below).
  >
  > As before all the operators "-border", "-frame", and
  >   "[-shave](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/option_link.cgi?shave)",
  >   only effect the real image on the virtual canvas and not the virtual
  >   canvas itself.
  >
  > <sub>[source](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#shave)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for this! Well, the `-shave` option works fine, at least it appears so. I didn't know that option (somehow always overlooked it) and it's quite helpful for the edges. Using something like `-shave 90x90` for the sample image, all edges are gone. *But*, the edges have never been the only problem. Even after removing them completely, and even with lenient settings such as `-fuzz 80%`, the upper white part is removed only, if at all. It seems there's some "dirt" in the white areas, generated by the scanner, which prevents `-trim` from working. Perhaps there's no better solution, though.

Comment: Not really sure yet because it didn't actually fix the problem or answer the full question, but just addressed a part of it. Anyway, I have awarded the bounty (+100) already.

Comment: It's actually precisely the image from the question which I'm working with: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVhlM.jpg I tried all commands and options with that image. Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks again! Together with your second answer, this does indeed work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

### Remove Dirt Specks or Noise from Images with ImageMagick

Below is what I used to get rid of the dirt specks in the image file from the image in your question, but I went ahead and used the [shave](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/option_link.cgi?shave) with the `90x90` first which is what you confirmed helped resolve the problem from the other solution I provided for the awarded bounty.

**Example Logic**

```
@ECHO ON

SET Convert="C:\Program Files\ImageMagick\Convert.exe"
%convert% C:\Folder\Circle.jpg -shave 90x90 C:\Folder\ShavedCircle.jpg
%convert% C:\Folder\ShavedCircle.jpg -write MPR:source ^
  -morphology close rectangle:3x4 ^
  -morphology erode square    MPR:source -compose Lighten -composite ^
  -morphology erode square    MPR:source -composite ^
  -morphology erode square    MPR:source -composite ^
  -morphology erode square    MPR:source -composite ^
  -morphology erode square    MPR:source -composite ^
  -morphology erode square    MPR:source -composite ^
  -morphology erode square    MPR:source -composite ^
  -morphology erode square    MPR:source -composite ^
  -morphology erode square    MPR:source -composite ^
C:\Folder\cleaned.jpg
```

---

### Before

[image]

### After

[image]

---

> Due to the nature of the ringing noise, all black noise specks are
>   separated by at least 1 pixel from the letters.
>
> One good approach to remove this noise would be to dilate the image so
>   that at least one "seed" part of each letter remains, then erode these
>   seeds while using the original image as a mask; in effect a flood-fill
>   for each letter.
>
> This way the shape of the letters and other large blobs is preserved
>   perfectly, and smaller blobs disappear.
>
> The biggest dilate that still leaves a part of each letter shape seems
>   to be a 3x4 rectangle for the example data; perhaps use something
>   smaller to be on the safe side.
>
> This command first dilates that 3x4 rectangle, end then erodes until
>   the letters are all whole again
>
> **Code**
>
> ```
> convert cleanup.tif -write MPR:source ^
>   -morphology close rectangle:3x4 ^
>   -morphology erode square    MPR:source -compose Lighten -composite ^
>   -morphology erode square    MPR:source -composite ^
>   -morphology erode square    MPR:source -composite ^
>   -morphology erode square    MPR:source -composite ^
>   -morphology erode square    MPR:source -composite ^
>   -morphology erode square    MPR:source -composite ^
>   -morphology erode square    MPR:source -composite ^
>   -morphology erode square    MPR:source -composite ^
>   -morphology erode square    MPR:source -composite ^
>   cleaned.png
> ```
>
> <sub>[source](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=18707)</sub>

---

### Further Resources

- [Morphology](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/)

Comment: Doing this before the other command (`-trim`) does clean up and trim the image as desired. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What ultimately provided perfect results, at least for my specific example shown in the original question (`scan.jpg`), was the following two-step solution:

```
convert \
    scan.jpg \
    -write MPR:source \
    -morphology close rectangle:3x4 \
    -clip-mask MPR:source \
    -morphology erode:8 square \
    +clip-mask \
    scan_intermediate.jpg

convert scan_intermediate.jpg -shave 40x40 -fuzz 10% -trim +repage scan_final.jpg
```

This solution is composed of three parts:

1. The command from my original question
2. The noise removal shown in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1222723/190188)
3. The `-shave` operator suggested in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1220822/190188)